# How do I add permissions on command?

Tags: java, bukkit

I can't find how to give a player certain permissions when they enter a command. The Bukkit API is very helpful in showing me possible methods when I just do player or permission. But nothing comes up which will give a player a certain permission. Here is the code I have to make it work:

(at the top of my main class)

```
public Permission blue = new Permission("Blue.allowed");
```

(In onEnable())

```
PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
pm.addPermission(blue);
```

I have this simple command that I want to give the player who types it in to get the `Blue` permission:

```
    public boolean onCommandAllowRed(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("give red") && sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;

        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

I just don't get the object model for perms, can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Bukkit doesn't make it easy to add permissions programmatically to a single player. Doing so would require a few headaches.

To make it easier I'd recommend using a plugin for permissions like bPermissions or PEX and then hook into their plugin and use the given methods to add the permission to the player.

To "hook in" you need to include the plugin into your build path and then get an instance of it. Typically plugins will tell you how to hook into then on their bukkit dev pages.

Answer (score 2):

To add on to baseball435's answer (which is completely correct), the easiest and most efficient way of doing this is by hooking into the [Vault API](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/vault/) rather than any individual plugin.
It is an adapter for almost every well-written permission plugin for Bukkit and will keep you from having to deal with different APIs from different systems.

Comment: Good to add; yes Vault acts as a wrapper around plugins that have similar functionality to make it easy for server owners to use whatever permission plugin, for example, that they like without having to worry about another plugin only requiring a specific type of permission plugin. Most plugin developers will use Vault's API to give the freedom of choice to server owners and also make it easier for themselves to develop plugins. You can check out Vault's dev page to see what other types of plugins they support if you're curious

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with this at first as well too, I found it out by myself, i also suggest a way of saving this otherwise on logout the permission will be lost.

This is how I manage permissions.

```
private static PermissionAttachment fetchPlayer(UUID uuid){
    Plugin plugin = Core.getPlugin();
    Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(uuid);
    if (player != null){
        PermissionAttachment perm = player.addAttachment(plugin);
        return perm;
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }

}

public static void addPermission(UUID uuid, String permission){
    PermissionAttachment perm = fetchPlayer(uuid);
    perm.setPermission(permission, true);
}

public static void removePermission(UUID uuid, String permission){
    PermissionAttachment perm = fetchPlayer(uuid);
    perm.unsetPermission(permission);
}
```